# Spotify Backstage 403 Forbidden after integrating Gitlab Auth provider

Tags: gitlab, multi-factor-authentication, backstage

followed the documentation in the spotify backstage , specifically here "https://backstage.io/docs/auth/gitlab/provider"
in order to configure authentication through gitlab app ,
we use self hosted gitlab server , and i got  403 Forbidden
[screenshot of the 403 Forbidden](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFRuy.png)

maybe the reason is because out gitlab is configurud also with 2fa, but Spotify Backstage doesn't mention how to handle 2fa, although it make sense almost everyone uses 2fa.

so my question is , how can i solve this ?

i tried to follow the documentation and i expected to be able to sign in to backstage with my gitlab details